# problemas function mapear sin usar map

Tags: javascript, map

Buenas queria pedirl ayuda con el siguiente ejercicio:

```
function mapear() {
  // Escribi una funcion mapear en el prototipo del objeto global 'Array'
  // que recibe una funcion callback , que se ejecuta por cada elemento del array
  // mapear los elementos de ese array segun la funcion callback
  // Esta funcion tiene que devolver un array nuevo con los elementos mapeados.
  // NO USAR LA FUNCION MAP DE ARRAYS.
  // ej:
  // var numeros = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  // numeros.mapear(function(numero) {
  //   return numero + 1;
  // }) devuelve [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Este fue mi intento, normalmente el curso que estoy haciendo me dice que hice mal pero en este solo me dice "TypeError: numbers.mapear is not a function" supongo que debe ser porque estoy haciendo mal el ejercicio y por ende no funciona pero no se como encararlo.

```
 // Tu código aca
 var otra = []
  var final = function(cb){
  for ( var i = 0; i<Array.length; i++){
    otra.push(cb(Array[i]))
  }
}

return otra;
}
```

intente también usar object.prototype.array pero tmbn me tirba error, aunque capaz era con eso pero lo hice mal.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_array.asp#:~:text=The%20prototype%20constructor%20allows%20you,Note%3A%20Array.

Comment: **Escribi una funcion mapear en el prototipo del objeto global 'Array'**. Tienes que escribir la función en el prototipo, esto hará que esté disponible para cualquier array. Si alguien quisiera usar tu función lo haría como `[].mapear(()=>{})` ó `Array().mapear(()=>{})` y de cualquier otra manera disponble para un array. Con la documentación que te dejaron en el otro comentario tienes una idea de cómo podrías hacerlo. Algo que debes de tener en cuenta es que esto en la práctica no se considera seguro/recomendable, por lo que deberías evitar usar esa práctica.

Comment: gracias @ricardo-dlc, con eso ya me saque la mayoria del problema, sin embargo cuando testeo me dice: array is not defined. tenes idea de porque pueda ser? y sobre lo otro  también me parecio raro que tenga ejercicios con map y aun asi me pidan esto asi, supongo q para entender como funciona map() . dejo aca mi ejercicio```array.prototype.cb = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
     this[i] = this[i].cb();
 }
  
 return cb();
  }
 }```

Comment: Tienes un typo, es `Array.prototype` no `array.prototype`.  Otra cosa que debes de tener en cuenta es que así como lo tienes ahora, tu función se llamará `cb` y no `mapear`.

Answer (score 1):

Es mas fácil de lo que parece, solo que debes tener en cuenta que cuando vamos a utilizar prototipos para modificarlos debes usar la `Clase` del prototipo asociado, que en este caso es `Array` **notese que esta en mayúsculas**.

Entonces el método mapear queda así:

```js
function mapear(callback){
  const x = []; this.forEach((s) => x.push(callback(s)));
  return x;
}

Array.prototype.mapear = mapear;

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const x = arr.mapear(el => el * 2);
console.log(x);
```

La clave es usar `this` para obtener el array original en el `callback`, de esta manera podremos hacer operaciones con cada uno de los valores del array dentro del recorriendolo con un `forEach`, que en caso de que tu profesor sea muy estricto pues se reemplaza con cualquier otro ciclo mas basico:

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    x.push(callback(this[i]));
}
```

La idea es ir metiendo los elementos en un nuevo array para no afectar el array original, y luego retornar el resultado, es importante decir que para cada valor de `this` (el arreglo), debe ser ejecutado el callback.

Es muy parecido a como funciona `map` realmente, incluso esta respuesta puede acortarse usando recursividad, pero por ahora quería mantener intacta mi cabeza.

**NOTESE** que los prototipos no son como las funciones, las cuales no importa en que lugar o momento las definas estas siempre existirán, en las modificaciones de los prototipos si que es importante donde pongas tu codigo.